# How can I set asp:Hyperlink text-decoration in code behind?

Tags: asp.net

I have a object reference to `asp:HyperLink`.  I see it has a Style property inherited from base.  But, how can I set `text-decoration = none` from code behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
myHyperlink.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none");
```

Comment: +1 - This works.  I was trying to do it with `Keys[]`, but couldnt get that to function.  Thanks